# Programmatically Control Monitors Through A KVM (DDI, VCP)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, sleep, kvm-switch, ci

I want to use a KVM switch with a few computers but I notice that I'm not able to use VCP commands to control it the way I can when the montior is plugged into the computer directly. For example, when it is plugged in directly, I can use Nirsoft ControlMyMonitor to see various information:

[image]

and I can also use it to control the monitor in various ways (put it into sleep mode, change the brightness, switch inputs, etc.)

However, when I use an HDMI KVM between the graphics card and the monitor, I'm no longer able to access the monitor:

[image]

I frequently need to toggle the monitors between sleep mode and being powered on, which I was able to write an Autohotkey script to automate by using the command line interface for ControlMyMonitor.

However, it no longer works once I use the KVM for the reason specified above.

Is there any way I can still programmatically control the monitor when I'm using the KVM? Or am I completely out of luck?